# share properties between builds in teamcity does not work

Tags: maven, teamcity

I have two builds - `Build Dev` and `Deploy Dev`. `Build Dev` is checking out the project which holds a `pom.xml` for maven build toolings. Therefore in this build I have access to properties like `%maven.project.version%`. The problem here is that `Deploy Dev` is actually in need of those properties as well but they are two different builds.

Now I read about **Snapshot Dependencies** where I can chain two builds into one build chain and they share a snapshot of the sources together. I even enabled the feature that they use the same build agent.

I thought that might be it but it was not. The build agent still is incompatible and there the `Deploy Build` is never triggered.

It is possible to access the properties of the dependency build (explained [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-DependenciesProperties)) **but** only for specific properties it seems. I was not able to access like this `%dep.build_dev.maven.project.name%`

Can anybody explain how I can share these maven properties between these two build?

Comment: if you can't access `%dep.build_dev.maven.project.name%` means you did not define parameter with name `maven.project.name` for build configuration `build_dev`

Comment: it is defined by build step "Maven". All steps afterwards *within* the build have access to this property. I just want to make it accessable to the next build as well without defining another Maven build step for it because it would be redundant

Comment: it should be defined as a parameter in build configuration, then it will be accessible in a dependent  build configurations

Comment: Can you show me exactly what you mean? I know about defining parameters but these would be "hardcoded" but the value changes if the maven `pom.xml` is changing after a commit or something. So I actually have to maintain it manually

Comment: not clear why you are referencing `pom.xml`... do you want to pass properties defined in `pom.xml` ?

Comment: The MAVEN build step is extracting the properties out of a given pom.xml and these properties are then available in the build step

Comment: There's a bug report from 2011. It also says the problem should be fixed but I think it's still there.
https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206898925-problem-with-maven-project-version-and-or-build-number-as-build-step-argument

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the evaluated properties of the Maven build are not available as parameters to downstream dependencies. When reading [this bug ticket](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206898925-problem-with-maven-project-version-and-or-build-number-as-build-step-argument?page=1#community_comment_206481155), it appears that these "outcome" parameters from Maven are handled differently by TeamCity.

But you can circumvent this be storing this transient parameter permanently!

1. Formally define a parameter `MAVEN_PROJECT_VERSION_EVALUATED` in your build config so it will be referable from your downstream dependency. Define it with an empty or arbitrary value - it will be overwritten by your build steps.[image: Defining a (empty) variable which will be overwrittne during the build]
2. Create a *Command Line* build step that stores `%maven.project.version%` in the parameter you just defined: `echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='MAVEN_PROJECT_VERSION_EVALUATED' value='%maven.project.version%']"`
3. Now you can reference that parameter from your downstream dependency: `%dep.<other build ID>.MAVEN_PROJECT_VERSION_EVALUATED%`